# failure to pass assertion test JS objects read as [object Object] instead of actual object values

Tags: javascript, object, assertion

I am currently trying to create my third assertion test -ever- for a function in JS. For some reason, the 'actual' value that I am passing to the assertion test is being read as '[object Object]' instead of the values that are actually inside the object that I am passing into the function. I have no idea of why is this happening (new to JS)... I got to make my assertion test to read the actual object when changing it to a string via JSON but since I need to compare the KEYS of my object, this doesn't help me much. ANy reference to what should I do or what to read about to solve this problem?

My assertion function :

```
function assertObjProperties(actual,expected,testName){
  if(Object.keys(actual) === Object.keys(expected)){
     console.log(`Passed. ${testName}`);
     } else {
       console.log(`Fail ${testName}. Expected ${expected}, but got ${actual}`);
     }
}
```

My call to the assertion test :

```
assertObjProperties(input[0], classListWithAges[0] , 'it contains the correct keys \n');
```

my 'input' and 'classListWithAges' :

```
var classListWithAges = [
  {"name":"Joe","age":11},
  {"name":"Jack","age":10},
  {"name":"John","age":11},
  {"name":"Fred","age":11},
  {"name":"Frank","age":11}
];


var input = [
  {"name":"Joe","age":11},
  {"name":"Jack","age":10},
  {"name":"John","age":11},
  {"name":"Fred","age":11},
  {"name":"Frank","age":11}
];
```

what the console returns :

```
Fail it contains the correct keys 
. Expected [object Object], but got [object Object]   // here the issue :/
```

Comment: You need to compare the keys individually. Keys are arrays. Like many other languages, when comparing arrays using equality operator you are actually comparing the array addresses (pointer). Since they are two separate arrays they will not be equal even if the values they contain are the same. You will need to use a loop to iterate over the keys and compare them. I strongly suggest using an assertion library like chai or should that already implement such testing

Comment: RIGHT! I was totally ignoring that. Will start reading about comparing arrays. Thank you